# Optimizing a Pandas DataFrame Transformation to Link two Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata, scalability

Given the following `df`:

```
   SequenceNumber | ID | CountNumber | Side | featureA | featureB
0   0             | 0  |  3          | Sell |  4       |  2              
1   0             | 1  |  1          | Buy  |  12      |  45
2   0             | 2  |  1          | Buy  |  1       |  4
3   0             | 3  |  1          | Buy  |  3       |  36
4   1             | 0  |  1          | Sell |  5       |  11
5   1             | 1  |  1          | Sell |  7       |  12
6   1             | 2  |  2          | Buy  |  5       |  35
```

I want to create a new `df` such that for every `SequenceNumber` value, it takes the rows with the `CountNumber == 1`, and creates new rows where if the `Side == 'Buy'` then put their `ID` in a column named `To`. Otherwise put their `ID` in a column named `From`. Then the empty column out of `From` and `To` will take the `ID` of the row with the `CountNumber > 1` (there is only one per each `SequenceNumber` value). The rest of the features should be preserved.

NOTE: basically each `SequenceNumber` represents one transactions that has either one seller and multiple buyers, or vice versa. I am trying to create a database that links the buyers and sellers where `From` is the Seller ID and `To` is the Buyer ID.

The output should look like this:

```
   SequenceNumber | From | To | featureA | featureB
0   0             | 0    |  1 |  12      |  45              
1   0             | 0    |  2 |  1       |  4
2   0             | 0    |  3 |  3       |  36
3   1             | 0    |  2 |  5       |  11
4   1             | 1    |  2 |  7       |  12
```

I implemented a method that does this, however I am using for loops which takes a long time to run on a large data. I am looking for a faster scalable method. Any suggestions?

Here is the original `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'SequenceNumber ': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
                   'ID': [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2], 
                   'CountNumber': [3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
                   'Side': ['Sell', 'Buy', 'Buy', 'Buy', 'Sell', 'Sell', 'Buy'],
                   'featureA': [4, 12, 1, 3, 5, 7, 5],
                   'featureB': [2, 45, 4, 36, 11, 12, 35]})
```

Comment: Can you provide the data in constructor format? (Paste `df.to_dict()` output.)

Comment: just added it at the end!

Comment: For each sequence number, there is always only either (1 sell multiple buys) or (multiple sells 1 buy), correct?

Comment: Does it make sense if I suggest splitting this problem in two parts and concatenate the resulting dataframes? Try to solve this for a dataframe where there is always 1 buyer and multiple sellers. Then do the same for a dataframe where there is always 1 seller en multiple buyers. Then concatenate those results. Combining these problems make it quite hard I think

Comment: @JarroVGIT yes there is always either (1 sell multiple buys) or (multiple sells 1 buy). I also believe that if you can split it, we can easily generalize it, no? But splitting would also work

Comment: You can only have `sequence number` from `0-4`

Comment: @JamiuS. no, ```SequenceNumber``` is unique to a transaction. So in the complete dataset, this feature takes even large values. In the example above, I have only selected two transactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Initial response.** To get the answer half complete. Split the data into sellers and buyers. Then merge it against itself on the sequence number:

```
ndf = df.query('Side == "Sell"').merge(
    df.query('Side == "Buy"'), on='SequenceNumber', suffixes=['_sell', '_buy']) \
    .rename(columns={'ID_sell': 'From', 'ID_buy': 'To'})
```

I then drop the side variable.

```
ndf = ndf.drop(columns=[i for i in ndf.columns if i.startswith('Side')])
```

This creates a very wide table:

```
   SequenceNumber  From  CountNumber_sell  featureA_sell  featureB_sell  To  CountNumber_buy  featureA_buy  featureB_buy
0               0     0                 3              4              2   1                1            12            45
1               0     0                 3              4              2   2                1             1             4
2               0     0                 3              4              2   3                1             3            36
3               1     0                 1              5             11   2                2             5            35
4               1     1                 1              7             12   2                2             5            35
```

This leaves you, however, with two `featureA` and `featureB` columns. I don't think your question clearly establishes which one takes precedence. Please provide more information on that.

Is it select the side with the lower `CountNumber`? Is it when `CountNumber == 1`? If the latter, then just null out the entries at the merge stage, do the merge, and then forward fill your appropriate columns to recover the proper values.

---

**Re nulling.** If you null the portions in `featureA` and `featureB` where the `CountNumber` is not 1, you can then create new version of those columns after the merge by forward filling and selecting.

```
s = df.query('Side == "Sell"').copy()
s.loc[s['CountNumber'] != 1, ['featureA', 'featureB']] = np.nan
b = df.query('Side == "Buy"').copy()
b.loc[b['CountNumber'] != 1, ['featureA', 'featureB']] = np.nan

ndf = s.merge(
    b, on='SequenceNumber', suffixes=['_sell', '_buy']) \
    .rename(columns={'ID_sell': 'From', 'ID_buy': 'To'})
ndf['featureA'] = ndf[['featureA_buy', 'featureA_sell']] \
    .ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]
ndf['featureB'] = ndf[['featureB_buy', 'featureB_sell']] \
    .ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]

ndf = ndf.drop(
    columns=[i for i in ndf.columns if i.startswith('Side') 
             or i.endswith('_sell') or i.endswith('_buy')])
```

The final version of `ndf` then is:

```
   SequenceNumber  From  To  featureA  featureB
0               0     0   1      12.0      45.0
1               0     0   2       1.0       4.0
2               0     0   3       3.0      36.0
3               1     0   2       5.0      11.0
4               1     1   2       7.0      12.0
```

Comment: This is a great answer, regarding the featureA and B, I want to keep that which has a ```CountNumber == 1```. So for the first 3 rows that would be ```featureA/B_buy``` and the last 2 rows that would be ```featureA/B_sell```

Comment: can you give some details on what you mean by "just null out the entries at the merge stage, do the merge, and then forward fill your appropriate columns"?

Comment: @devCharaf edited to include code re forward filling

Answer (score 2):

You can reshape with a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), select the features to keep with a [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and rework the output with [`groupby.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) then [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
features = list(df.filter(like='feature'))

out = (
   # repeat the rows with CountNumber > 1
 df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['CountNumber'])]
   # rename Sell/Buy into from/to and de-duplicate the rows per group
   .assign(Side=lambda d: d['Side'].map({'Sell': 'from', 'Buy': 'to'}),
           n=lambda d: d.groupby(['SequenceNumber', 'Side']).cumcount()
          )
   # mask the features where CountNumber > 1
   .assign(**{f: lambda d, f=f: d[f].mask(d['CountNumber'].gt(1)) for f in features})
   .drop(columns='CountNumber')
   # reshape with a pivot
   .pivot(index=['SequenceNumber', 'n'], columns='Side')
 )

out = (
 pd.concat([out['ID'], out.drop(columns='ID').groupby(level=0, axis=1).first()], axis=1)
   .reset_index('SequenceNumber')
)
```

Output:

```
   SequenceNumber  from  to  featureA  featureB
n                                              
0               0     0   1      12.0      45.0
1               0     0   2       1.0       4.0
2               0     0   3       3.0      36.0
0               1     0   2       5.0      11.0
1               1     1   2       7.0      12.0
```

###### atlernative using a `merge` like [suggested by ifly6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75379513/16343464):

```
features = list(df.filter(like='feature'))

df1 = df.query('Side=="Sell"').copy()
df1[features] = df1[features].mask(df1['CountNumber'].gt(1))

df2 = df.query('Side=="Buy"').copy()
df2[features] = df2[features].mask(df2['CountNumber'].gt(1))

out = (df1.merge(df2, on='SequenceNumber').rename(columns={'ID_x': 'from', 'ID_y': 'to'})
          .set_index(['SequenceNumber', 'from', 'to'])
          .filter(like='feature')
          .pipe(lambda d: d.groupby(d.columns.str.replace('_.*?$', '', regex=True), axis=1).first())
          .reset_index()
      )
```

Output:

```
   SequenceNumber  from  to  featureA  featureB
0               0     0   1      12.0      45.0
1               0     0   2       1.0       4.0
2               0     0   3       3.0      36.0
3               1     0   2       5.0      11.0
4               1     1   2       7.0      12.0
```

Comment: Please check the update if you're only interested in the features that match the CountNumber with value 1

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach

```py
df1 = df.loc[df['CountNumber'] == 1].copy()
df1['From'] = (df1['ID'].where(df1['Side'] == 'Sell', df1['SequenceNumber']
                .map(df.loc[df['CountNumber'] > 1].set_index('SequenceNumber')['ID']))
                )
df1['To'] = (df1['ID'].where(df1['Side'] == 'Buy', df1['SequenceNumber']
                .map(df.loc[df['CountNumber'] > 1].set_index('SequenceNumber')['ID']))
                )

df1 = df1.drop(['ID', 'CountNumber', 'Side'], axis=1)
df1 = df1[['SequenceNumber', 'From', 'To', 'featureA', 'featureB']]
df1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(df1)
```

---

```
   SequenceNumber  From  To  featureA  featureB
0               0     0   1        12        45
1               0     0   2         1         4
2               0     0   3         3        36
3               1     0   2         5        11
4               1     1   2         7        12
```